# UITableView Cell Image Gets Larger On Click

Tags: ios, image, uitableview, scale

I have a UITableView which loads the icons for my other apps.

They look fine at a good 57x57 automatic size in a cell which is 70px height.

When I click on a cell, the image suddenly scales up to 70x70 and I have no idea how to stop it.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: Is it a custom cell? Did you try to add heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate?

Comment: @cocoakomali I already have that one. 70 isn't the default height for a cell.

Comment: Can you share some code? Making of cell, delegates?

Answer (score 0):

So the way I understand it is you are adding a UIImageView as a subview to a cellview.

The way I do this that works great even where the image is smaller than the cells row hieght  is add the UIImageView in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` then set the frame to something that fits in the cell and is the image size.

You might be building the custom cells in the UI Builder, but explicitly setting the frame of the image view to `CGRectMake(imageview.frame.bounds.x,imageview.frame.bounds.y,57,57)` and setting the autoresize property for vertical and horizontal to none should stop it from scaling up.